# Android Save Live Video Stream to Storage using libvlc

Tags: android, xamarin, streaming, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I'm trying to save a live video stream to storage in Android App using libvlc.
I can do it on PC with command line and it work fine, I record the file and can view it afterwards.

But in the app the file records, it's only 151B big which is probably empty and if I try to open it I get message "Cannot play this video format"

My question is, is it possible to record to storage in Android with libvlc?

I'm fairly new to programming so any suggestions would help

```
    const string VIDEO_URL = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov";

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Core.Initialize();           
        using (var libvlc = new LibVLC())
        using (var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libvlc))
        {
            var media = new Media(libvlc, VIDEO_URL, FromType.FromLocation);
            var currentDirectory = "/storage/emulated/0/dcim/";
            var destination = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "record4.mp4");

            // Define stream output options. 
            // In this case stream to a file with the given path and play locally the stream while streaming it.
            media.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264}:std{access=file,dst=" + destination + "}");

            // Start recording
             mediaPlayer.Play(media);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be possible. Do you get any error? Share full logs please

Comment: @mtz I've add the log output, hope it's is what you asked for. Thanks

Comment: You're creating 2 mediaplayers and 2 media, fix this first?

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try and fix it. is there a specific line in the log that refers to the 2 mediaplayers so that I will know if I've fixed it?

Comment: No. You're calling `new MediaPlayer()` twice.

Comment: Hi mtz, I've changed the code so that it only calls mediaPlayer.Play(media);, but the results is still the same. Record file that is empty and can not be played.

Comment: Update the code in your question. Share **full** logs

Comment: Hi mtz, I've updated the code and add the logs below. Thanks

Comment: This is unreadable. Use code formatting please

Comment: Hi mtz. Sorry for that, BUT I found my problem. Need to stop the recording with out closing the program. Thanks for your help it work, just need a proper way to stop the recording. Will add code as soon as I have it fixed. Thanks you again.

Answer (score 0):

The mediaplayer must be stop be for closing the app. Here is a interim solution.
Will update it as soon as I have a proper solution.

```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    const string VIDEO_URL = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov";

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Core.Initialize();           
        using (var libvlc = new LibVLC())
        using (var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libvlc))
        {
            var media = new Media(libvlc, VIDEO_URL, FromType.FromLocation);
            var currentDirectory = "/storage/emulated/0/dcim/";
            var destination = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "record7.mp4");

            // Define stream output options. 
            // In this case stream to a file with the given path and play locally the stream while streaming it.

            media.AddOption(":sout=#file{dst=" + destination + "}");
            media.AddOption(":sout-keep");


            // Start recording
             mediaPlayer.Play(media);

            *// Added these lines that create event handler error for Xamarin.forms, 
            // but at least it stops mediaplayer before closing App. and the 
            // recording can be play afterwards.*
            Console.WriteLine($"Recording in {destination}");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a destination file and also parse URL as URI not as a path,
add following arg to libvlc

```
Final ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
args.add (" &ndash; aout=opensles");
args.add (" &ndash; vout=android_display");
args.add (" &ndash; audio-time-stretch");
args.add (" &ndash; no-sub-autodetect-file");
args.add (" &ndash; swscale-mode=0");
args.add (" &ndash; network-caching=500");
args.add (" &ndash; no-drop-late-frames");
args.add (" &ndash; no-skip-frames");
args.add (" &ndash; avcodec-skip-frame");
args.add (" &ndash; avcodec-hw=any");
mLibVLC = new LibVLC (mContext, args);
```